# Seleniumt webelement with spaces

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to locate a web element in selenium with an id that has 5 spaces before and 5 spaces after the word `ac`?

Example `id="     ac     "`

Answer (score 3):

While there are probably other ways to access the web element, the only way to ensure, based solely on the information you were given, is to use the locator:

```
//*[@id='     ac     ']
```

The reason this is the correct answer is that because while you could use:

```
//*[contains(@id,"ac")]
```

You don't know that the xpath will be unique now, or in the future.

Similarly,

```
//*[normalize-space(@id)='ac']
```

will work for the element described, but it will also match other potential elements, like with any combination of spaces before and/or after "ac"

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(@id)='ac']")).click
```

Comment: Putting some text context to your code may help the future readers. See why ['Try This: {code}' Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality) are not helpful to other readers and are prone to downvotes.

Comment: @DebanjanB sure, I will write code along with the corresponding explanation henceforth.